# byte-buddy share variables between multiple instrumentations

Tags: byte-buddy

I am instrumenting different classes and would like to use some values between these instrumentations. Can someone please help me here. I am setting some context variables, but facing race conditions and values are getting overwritten. Any ideas/thoughts welcome.

Thanks!

I have tried to setup context and share values using context

Expected : If in an api, I am saving requestURL and details, I would like to use these values when I am instrumenting other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transport values from one method to another, adding a variable would not help you as those are only visible locally. You could of course adjust all method signatures within a call chain but that wouldbe tedious.

Instead, I would recomnend you to have some global, thread-local context where you can store these values from one method and receive it from another. If you have a context-switch somewhere in between, things get more complicated and you need to instrument the context switch to transfer the state from one thread to another.